# Regex to get date from string

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to get date out of the following String

```
anything-2011.01.17-16.50.19.xml
```

Is this a correct one

```
^\\.(.+)-([0-9.]+-[0-9.]+)\\.xml$
```

?

Comment: Do you get the correct result?

Comment: How robust does this have to be? It will match your string if you take out the first `\ `, but will also match (for example) `anything-1.1.1.1.....1.-..xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here is checking the format YYYY.MM.DD-HH.MM.SS

```
^(.*?)-(\d{4}(?:\.\d{2}){2}-\d{2}(?:\.\d{2}){2})\.xml$
```

But it does not verify if the date or the time is a valid value.

[Online check on regexr](http://regexr.com?2tntr).

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
^.*?-([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)\..*$
```

You should also accept your recent questions.

Comment: well this only gives me 16.50.19 and not 2011.01.17-16.50.19.

Comment: It returns it in two groups - in first you have date and in second you have time. If you change `([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)` to `([0-9.]+-[0-9.]+)` you will get it in one group

Answer (score 0):

The following regex is a bit stricter. It will match years in the range 1900 to 2099, months in 01 to 12 and days in 01 to 31.

```
^.*?-((19|20)\d\d\.(0[1-9]|1[1-2])\.(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))-.*?.xml$
```

Comment: Month MM check fails for 10 October. More refined: ^.*?-((19|20)\d\d\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))-.*?.xml$