# How to use regular expression to get date from text

Tags: php, regex

I have a text `Summary for rxd7865 November 13, 2012 to November 13, 2012`.

I want to fetch only date string like `November 13, 2012` from above text.

How I can use regular expressions in PHP to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? I'm sure it's easy to google how to use regex in PHP... are you having difficulty with some specific part of the regex?

Comment: How fixed is the date format?

Comment: try http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php

Comment: Try the below link... it will help you...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961997/regex-to-get-date-from-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex:

```
preg_match('/(?<the_date>(January|February|March) [0-9]{2}, 20[0-9]{2})/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[the_date];
```

The explanation:

```
() // are called capture groups or matches
(?<name>) // are named capture groups or named matches
| // separator between a list of alternative matches
[] // is a character class
[0-9] // is a character class that allows only characters from 0 to 9
{} // is a repetition specifier
[]{2} // allows the character class to repeat twice
```

Comment: Only it doesn't work. You forgot the regex delimiters and the `to...` part (which of course the OP can figure out himself).

Comment: Good catch with the regex delimiters. The rest is something the OP **has** to figure out for himself. I also didn't include all 12 possible months for example.

Comment: Thanks for yours all discussion and above regular expression is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

With [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), it uses [PCRE syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Comment: I *think* that's not the answer the OP is hoping for... :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker then the question should have been worded more specific ;)

Comment: @fab, it's a pretty specific question. Lazy but specific.