# Need a regex to extract a substring

Tags: java, regex, jsp

I am struggling to figure out a decent way to extract a substring from the below string.

```
Inputs: 

Invoice 1800000173 of 06/18/2014/150 USD Discnt to 07/02/2014

Invoice 1200000000 of 02.04.2014/150 Details
```

The above are the 2 possible combinations.

```
Expected Output:

Invoice 1800000173 of 06/18/2014

Invoice 1200000000 of 02.04.2014
```

There is a similar question asked here - [Regex to get date from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961997/regex-to-get-date-from-string) but that didn't help me here. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

```
"Invoice (\d+) of (\d\d[./]\d\d[./]\d{4})"
```

Two capturing groups, first of one or more digit for invoice number, second for the date portion.  Escaping the backslashes will also need to be done appropriately.

Comment: I removed some unnecessary backslashes and fixed the number of digits in a year.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but its giving null. tried like this: str.match(regex), where str is the input and regex is what you mentioned

Comment: Well, since str.match() returns boolean I have no idea what you mean by it 'giving null'.  Furthermore, str.match() will do nothing for capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
([0-9]+) of ([0-9]{1,2}[,/][0-9]{1,2}[,/][0-9]{1,4})
```

first group contains invoice number and second date.

Comment: Thanks. This worked well for the first input but not for the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Invoice [0-9]+ of ([0-9]{2}[\/.][0-9]{2}[\/.][0-9]{4})
```

Answer (score 0):

Regx for your need will be as,

```
Invoice\\s\\d+\\sof\\s\\d+[/.]\\d+[/.]+\\d+
```

And use pattern matcher to get the required sub string.. As,

```
public class StringProcesing {

    public void fetchSubString() {
        String s1 = "Invoice 1800000173 of 06/18/2014/150 USD Discnt to 07/02/2014";
        String s2 = "Invoice 1200000000 of 02.04.2014/150 Details";

        Pattern p = Pattern
                .compile("Invoice\\s\\d+\\sof\\s\\d+[/.]\\d+[/.]+\\d+");
        Matcher matchS1 = p.matcher(s1);
        while(matchS1.find()) {
            System.out.println(matchS1.group());
        }
        Matcher matchS2 = p.matcher(s2);
        while(matchS2.find()) {
            System.out.println(matchS2.group());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringProcesing obj = new StringProcesing();
        obj.fetchSubString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Invoice 1800000173 of 06/18/2014
Invoice 1200000000 of 02.04.2014
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#replaceFirst` to capture what you want and discard rest:

```
String str = "Invoice 1800000173 of 06/18/2014/150 USD Discnt to 07/02/2014";
String m = str.replaceFirst("^.*(Invoice +\\d+ +of +\\d{2}[./]\\d{2}[./]\\d{4}).*$", "$1");
//=> Invoice 1800000173 of 06/18/2014

str = "Invoice 1200000000 of 02.04.2014/150 Details";
m = str.replaceFirst("^.*(Invoice +\\d+ +of +\\d{2}[./]\\d{2}[./]\\d{4}).*$", "$1");
//=> Invoice 1200000000 of 02.04.2014
```

Answer (score 0):

I have nice solution :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexFun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Inputs: \r\n" + "\r\n" + "Invoice 1800000173 of 06/18/2014/150 USD Discnt to 07/02/2014\r\n"
                + "\r\n" + "Invoice 1200000000 of 02.04.2014/150 Details";
        Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile("^Invoice \\d{10} of \\d{1,2}[ ._/-]\\d{1,2}[ ._/-]\\d{2,4}",
                Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher matcher = emailPattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String group = matcher.group();
            System.out.println("group=" + group);
        }
    }
}
```

By enabling `MULTILINE` mode you can use caret **^** to match start of each line.

Character set `[ ._/-]` allows you to match any date separator.